# BST program in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

Please help me with this. I keep getting seg faults!
I want to use recursion to create and insert a new node.
Please help me debug this.

```
//Create a Binary Search Tree From an array.
struct Tree
{
        int data;
    struct Tree *lchild;
    struct Tree *rchild;
};
struct Tree *root = NULL;
struct Tree *node(int val)
{
    struct Tree *tempnode;
    tempnode = (struct Tree*)malloc(sizeof(struct Tree));
    tempnode->data = val;
    tempnode->rchild = NULL;
    tempnode->lchild = NULL;
    return tempnode;
}

void createTree(struct Tree *curr, int val)
{
    struct Tree *newnode = node(val);

    if (curr == NULL)
        curr = newnode;
    else if(val < curr->data)
    {
        createTree(curr->lchild,val);
    }
    else if(val > curr->data)
    {
        createTree(curr->rchild,val);

    }
    else
        printf("Error Similar data found\n");
}

void inorder(struct Tree *root)
{
    if (root->lchild != NULL)
        inorder(root->lchild);
    printf("[%d]    ",root->data);
    if (root->rchild != NULL)
        inorder(root->rchild);
}
int main()
{
//    root = NULL;
    int i = 0, arr[5] = {41,12,32,23,17};
    for(i;i<5;i++)
        createTree(root,arr[i]);
    inorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

why do I keep getting seg fault. Can someone explain me?
Am I doing something I should not? Or am I missing at some point?

Comment: Your real code **does** `#include` `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdio.h>`, doesn't it?

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 2):

The root of the tree is not assigned anywhere; in your function `createTree` you probably think that it is assigned in:

```
if (curr == NULL)
    curr = newnode;
```

But `curr` is local to the function and does not affect `root`. You need to change the argument `curr` to be a pointer to pointer, otherwise the function does not work for assigning the root node, or child nodes. The root of the tree is not assigned anywhere; in your function `createTree` you probably think that it is assigned in:

```
if (curr == NULL)
    curr = newnode;
```

But `curr` is local to the function and does not affect `root` even if you gave it as the argument `curr`. You need to change the argument `curr` to be a pointer to pointer, otherwise the function does not work for assigning the root node, or child nodes. That is, the function declaration becomes:

```
void createTree(struct Tree **curr, int val)
```

Of course you must then change the use of `curr` inside the function accordingly (i.e., the address pointed to is `*curr` where it used to be `curr`), calls of the function need to pass the address, and not value, of the pointer (e.g., `createTree(&root, arr[i])`).

**edit**: Or, indeed, have the function return `curr` and always assign the return value to the relevant pointer at every place where you call `createTree`, thanks to @JonathanLeffler for the observation.

Comment: Alternatively, use `struct Tree *createTree(struct Tree *curr, int val)` and `return curr;` at the end and invoke it as `root = createTree(root, arr[i]);`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, good point, that would indeed be simpler for this function, I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Learn to use a debugger!

Stepping through the main function, you would have seen that the value of `root` would have remained `NULL` after each call to `createTree`

The `createTree` function is not modifying the value of `root`, but only modifying its copy of the value of `root`.

Your `createTree` function needs to take a `struct Tree **curr`, a pointer-to-a-pointer. This allows the function to modify the original value, not the local copy.